# Notmapped property and OData 4 endpoint can't get the property to show on front end

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata

I am using Entity Framework Core 5 with OData 4 endpoints in my project. I am having an issue with a `[NotMapped]` property not showing up to be used in my front end. I have read that OData ignores not mapped properties but I have not found a solution on how to get OData to not ignore the property so that I can use it in my front end without adding it to my database.

What I am trying to accomplish is to include the count of each category assigned in the asset table.

Here is what I have for my DTO

```
public class CategoryDto : DropDownDto
{
    /*
     * String property that gets/sets the category name
     */
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

and in my `CategoriesController` I have this

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IQueryable<CategoryDto>>> GetCategories()
{
    var categories = await _context.Categories
            .Include(a => a.Assets)
            .Select(l => new CategoryDto()
            {
                Id = l.Id,
                CategoryName = l.CategoryName,
                Count = l.Assets.Count
            })
            .ToListAsync();
    var categoryDto = _mapper.Map<List<Category>>(categories);

    return Ok(categoryDto);
}
```

When I run my app and put a breakpoint on the return and view the data I can see that count is working as expected. It has the proper count of assets assigned to a category which is what I want

[image]

But when I run postman to see the values all I get is this

```
"value": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "categoryName": "Computers"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "categoryName": "Tools"
        }
    ]
```

So the issue is how to I get the OData endpoint to included the notmapped property?

Any insight would be great, if more info is needed please ask and Ill get it for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the OData GetEdmModel method, use the following commands to add the `[NotMapped]` property to the IEdmModel object.

```
    IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    { 
        var odataBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        odataBuilder.EntitySet<Student>("Students");
                    
        odataBuilder.EntityType<Student>().Property(c => c.Score);
        //or using the HasKey method.
        //odataBuilder.EntityType<Student>().HasKey(x => x.Score);

        return odataBuilder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

the `Student` model like this:

```
public class Student
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

Before adding the `[NotMapped]` property to the IEdmModel object. The result like this:

[image]

After adding the `[NotMapped]` property to the IEdmModel object. the result as below:

[image]